# значение, которое хранит массив, не умножается

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Олимпиадная задача. По его достижению, нужно умножить максимальное на данный момент значение массива на `gothair`, и привести `gothair=1`. Иначе `gothair++`. Но наибольшее значение массива почему-то не изменяется по просьбе и не умножается на `gothair`, в чем ошибка?

Ввод:5
73 31 96 24 46
Вывод: 96, но должен быть 380

Одного неформала выгнали с работы, и теперь ему надо как-то зарабатывать себе на жизнь. Поразмыслив, он решил, что сможет иметь очень неплохие деньги на продаже собственных волос. Известно, что пункты приема покупают волосы произвольной длины стоимостью С у.е. за каждый сантиметр. Так как волосяной рынок является очень динамичным, то цена одного сантиметра волос меняется каждый день как и курс валют. Неформал является очень хорошим бизнес-аналитиком. Он смог вычислить, какой будет цена одного сантиметра волос в каждый из ближайших N дней (для удобства пронумеруем дни в хронологическом порядке от 0 до N-1). Теперь он хочет определить, в какие из этих дней ему следует продавать волосы, чтобы по истечению всех N дней заработать максимальное количество денег. Заметим, что волосы у неформала растут только ночью и вырастают на 1 сантиметр за ночь. Следует также учесть, что до 0-го дня неформал с горя подстригся наголо и к 0-му дню длина его волос составляла 1 сантиметр.

Входные данные

В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записано целое число N (0 < N ≤ 100). Во второй строке через пробел заданы N натуральных чисел, не превосходящих 100, соответствующие стоимости C[i] 1 сантиметра волос за каждый i-й день.

Выходные данные

В единственную строку выходного файла OUTPUT.TXT нужно вывести максимальную денежную сумму, которую может заработать неформал за N дней

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int maxel(int* c, int i, int n)
{
    int maxe = i;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (c[maxe] > c[i])maxe = i;
    }

    return maxe;
}
int main()
{
    freopen("INPUT.TXT", "r", stdin);
    freopen("OUTPUT.TXT", "w", stdout);
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int* c = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> c[i];
    }

    int maxe = maxel(c, 0, n);
    int gotmoney = 0;
    int gothair = 1
                  ;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (c[i - 1] != c[maxe])
        {
            gothair++;
        }
        else
        {
            gotmoney += (gothair * (c[maxe]));
            gothair = 1;
            maxe = maxel(c, i, n);
        }
    }

    cout << gotmoney;
}
```

Comment: По достижению его - кого?

Comment: А у меня Ваш код на выходе 101 дает. Хм, к чему бы это ?

Comment: @Harry Наибольшего элемента массива

Comment: Откровенно говоря, понятнее не стало. Вы бы уж давали тогда полный текст задачи.

Comment: добавлю текст задачи

Comment: Вообщем, Ваша ф-ия `maxel` делает отнюдь не то, что Вы от нее ожидаете. Хотя, я не могу быть уверенным в том, что я знаю, чего Вы от нее ожидаете )) Судя по условию задачи - поиск макс. элемента с заданной позиции. Код обновил, проверьте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int max( int*, int, int );

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 73, 31, 96, 24, 46 };

    /*
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "\nFromPos=" << i << " maxPos=" << max(arr, i, 6);
    }
    */

    int acc = 0;
    int cff = 1;
    int pos = max(arr, 0, 5);

    for( int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        if( arr[i-1] != arr[pos])
        {
            ++cff;
        }
        else
        {
            acc += cff * arr[pos];
            cff = 1;
            pos = max(arr, i, 5);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nRes=" << acc;
    return 0;
}

int max( int* ptr, int fromPos, int size )
{
    int res = fromPos;
    for( int i = fromPos; i < size; ++i )
    {
        if( ptr[i] > ptr[res])
            res = i;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Да там 5 - это количество элементов массива :) Единственное, что я понял из условия, откровенно говоря...

Comment: @Harry, вот оно что... )) Вообще, согласен с Вами - было бы очень не плохо, если бы был предоставлен оригинальный текст задачи.

Comment: Заменил свой maxel на твой max и все заработало норм хмхмхм

Comment: хотя не вижу различия

Comment: А Вы на одном и том же наборе данных запустите обе ф-ии - сравните результаты.